# Доступ к классу li в css

Tags: css, ul

У меня такая структура меню

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-657"><a href="#">обувь</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-658" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-658"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/leather/">женская обувь</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-656"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/mens-footwear/">мужская обувь</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Сейчас меню выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне в css прописать путь, чтобы доступиться к редактированию стиля li для подпунктов меню "женская обувь" и "мужская обувь" ?
Нужно, что бы выглядело так же, как в родителе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот полная разметка меню

```
<ul style="display: none;" id="responsive-menu" class="ul"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-521"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/">Главная</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-523"><a href="#">Категория купонов</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-657"><a href="#">обувь</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-658"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/leather/">женская обувь</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-656"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/mens-footwear/">мужская обувь</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-670"><a href="#">женская одежда</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-666"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/kardigani/">кардиганы</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-667"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/swim-dress/">купальники</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-668"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/women-jacket/">куртки</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-669"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/dresses/">платья</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-525"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/electronics/">электроника</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-529"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/avto/">автотовары</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-662"><a href="#">всё для детей</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-663"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/child-shoes/">детская обувь</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-664"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/child-wear/">детская одежда</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-665"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/games/">игрушки</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-661"><a href="#">мужская одежда</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-645"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/maiki/">майки и футболки</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-648"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/leather/">кожа и замша</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-647"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/jakets/">костюмы и пиджаки</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-649"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/coat/">куртки и пальто</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-650"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/belts/">ремни и пояса</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-646"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/skirts/">рубашки</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-660"><a href="#">украшения</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-652"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/bijouterie/">бижутерия</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-653"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/clock/">часы</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-654"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/jewelry/">ювелирные украшения</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-674"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/accessories/">аксессуары</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-578"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/blog/">Статьи</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: вся необходимая разметка и стили должны быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: и стили тоже нужно добавить в вопрос

Comment: добавил, теперь всё сразу видно в вопросе. Стиле не нужно мне помогать составлять, просто нужно написать правильный доступ к li. А Сами стили в фигурных скобках я сам напишу

Comment: какой уровень вложенности меню может быть? вообще похоже нужно просто по классу: `.menu-item-type-taxonomy` выбирать и им стиль писать

Comment: что значит "выглядело так же, как в родителе"? разве оно сейчас не выглядит также как в родителе?

Comment: по классу .menu-item-type-taxonomy {list-style-image: url('../images/element.png'); } попробовал, но не появляются эти штучки, как перед меню обувь

Comment: ещё какие-то советы можно? пробовал выбрать ещё по классу .menu-item-658 {list-style-image: url('../images/element.png'); }. Тоже не дало результат

Comment: собственно стоит посмотреть какой из стилей применяется к родителю и как он выставляет эту галочку, наверняка за это отвечает класс _menu-item-has-children_

Comment: _по классу .menu-item-type-taxonomy {list-style-image: url('../images/element.png'); } попробовал, но не появляются эти штучки, как перед меню обувь_ очевидно в этом случае стоит посмотреть какой из классов перебил эти настройки

Comment: разместил всю разметку меню. Может вам удастся увидеть какой из классов перебивает..

Comment: без стилей - нет, перебивать может любой, это можно увидеть в инструментах разработчика в хроме например, выделив нужный элемент и посмотрев какие именно стили к нему применились

Comment: ок, всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы советовал сделать немного по-другому. Только вместо символа в before используйте картинку и не забудьте указать ширину и высоту.

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 


.menu-item-657 .sub-menu {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.menu-item-657 .sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.menu-item-657 .sub-menu a:before {
  content: '▶';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  font-size: .5em;
  margin-top: .3em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="responsive-menu" class="ul">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-521"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-523"><a href="#">Категория купонов</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-657"><a href="#">обувь</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-658"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/leather/">женская обувь</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-656"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/mens-footwear/">мужская обувь</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-670"><a href="#">женская одежда</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-666"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/kardigani/">кардиганы</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-667"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/swim-dress/">купальники</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-668"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/women-jacket/">куртки</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-669"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/dresses/">платья</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-525"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/electronics/">электроника</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-529"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/avto/">автотовары</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-662"><a href="#">всё для детей</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-663"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/child-shoes/">детская обувь</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-664"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/child-wear/">детская одежда</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-665"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/games/">игрушки</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-661"><a href="#">мужская одежда</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-645"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/maiki/">майки и футболки</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-648"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/leather/">кожа и замша</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-647"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/jakets/">костюмы и пиджаки</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-649"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/coat/">куртки и пальто</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-650"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/belts/">ремни и пояса</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-646"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/skirts/">рубашки</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-660"><a href="#">украшения</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-652"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/bijouterie/">бижутерия</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-653"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/clock/">часы</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-654"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/jewelry/">ювелирные украшения</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-coupon_cat menu-item-674"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/coupon-categories/accessories/">аксессуары</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-578"><a href="http://ali-coupons.net/blog/">Статьи</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!